# What is the meaning of "with drift" in the arima model produced by auto.arima function?

Tags: time-series, arima

[image: ARIMA (1,0,2)(1,1,2)[12] with drift]

What is the meaning of with drift in the ARIMA model produced by the auto.arima() function?
What is the difference between a model ARIMA(1,0,2)(1,1,2)[12] and ARIMA(1,0,2)(1,1,2)[12] with drift? (The difference of a model with drift and without a drift?

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the image in your post, so please include the software output as text

Comment: You can have a look at [ARIMA modelling in R](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html) by Rob Hyndman; this has been explained there.